# Can we force the "Allow only users in specific security group to share externally" to only work with sharepoint and not on onedrive

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, external-users

As per my knowledge if we define that only users inside specific security group can share with external users, as follow:-

[image: admin]

then this will be applied to SharePoint sites + onedrive personal sites. now inside our organization we want everyone to share files with external users inside their one-drives, while only allow users inside the above security group to share the sites with external users.. so is this possible? or the above settings will get applied to sharepoint and onedrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m afraid it is not supported to apply external sharing for SharePoint Online and OneDrive separately.

The external sharing settings will apply to both SharePoint Online and OneDrive, since personal OneDrive sites are included in SharePoint Online sites.

If you navigate to `OneDrive admin center > Sharing`, you will see an annotation saying:

> Your sharing setting for OneDrive can't be more permissive than your
>   settings for SharePoint.

[image]